# Forcing merge one branch into another

Tags: git

I'm working on setting up a pull-request to get changes from branch 'source' into branch 'target', but there are numerous conflicts, files have been moved and renamed within the repository. I've tried creating a branch off 'target' (let's call it 'target-staging'), then merging 'source' into 'target-staging'. When IntelliJ prompts me to address the conflicts, I chose 'theirs' for all the files, however, I get the following:

> Cannot check the working tree for unmerged files because of an error.
> Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files. hint: Fix
> them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm  ' hint: as
> appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit. Exiting because of
> an unresolved conflict.

Next I ran `git status` which showed many files in green as "modified" and 3 files in red as "both deleted", so I ran `git rm` for each of the three. `git status` then showed everything in green Then I showed a large number of files under 'Local Changes', so I committed and pushed these changes.

At this point I thought things were good, but as a sanity check I checked out 'source' into one directory and 'target-staging' into another and used WinMerge to compare the contents and found quite a few differences, including missing and additional files and directories. So the above didn't do what I was intending. I'm not exactly sure where to go from here, short of brute-force copying everything over from the 'source' branches directory and pushing it all into 'target-staging' from there.

Comment: Resolving conflicts by choosing just "theirs" (or "ours" for that matter) is barely ever the correct thing to do. Conflicts happen for a reason. You really have to get to the ground of the conflicts and resolve them in a reasonable manner. Since you seem to be behind upstream a significant amount of commits, to simplify conflicts, you can merge upstream piecewise (a dozen commits or so per merge).